MySQL 8.0.37 Why DATETIME is different than the one inserted?
I'm using MySQL 8.0.37.
I have a table which has a DATETIME to store a datetime in UTC,
mysql> desc payments;
+-------------------------+---------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field                   | Type          | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+-------------------------+---------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| id                      | varchar(21)   | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
| received_at             | datetime      | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
+-------------------------+---------------+------+-----+---------+-------+

then I converted the local dates to UTC dates and insert the records like this,
insert into `payments` (`id`, `received_at`) values
('GX1CzNsgBr2aJcQNqn_eC', '2024-04-30 16:00:00.000'),
('7tlZag3tOQyBAX6ncygnn', '2024-05-01 15:59:59.999');

and when I select the records ...
mysql> select id, received_at from payments order by received_at;
+-----------------------+---------------------+
| id                    | received_at         |
+-----------------------+---------------------+
| GX1CzNsgBr2aJcQNqn_eC | 2024-04-30 16:00:00 |
| 7tlZag3tOQyBAX6ncygnn | 2024-05-01 16:00:00 |
+-----------------------+---------------------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)

The first record shows 2024-04-30 16:00:00 correctly but the last record shows 2024-05-01 16:00:00 and not 2024-05-01 15:59:59?
What am I missing here?

Can't tell from the above output, if you have your DATETIME field configured with a fractional seconds precision - if not, that's the first thing you need to do. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/fractional-seconds.html

@CBroe thanks for your pointer and the values show correctly after I removed the fractional seconds from the insert statements!

@CBroe was correct as this has to do with the Fractional Seconds in Time Values. I have change the received_at column definition to
mysql> desc payments;
+-------------+---------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field       | Type          | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+-------------+---------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| id          | varchar(21)   | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
| received_at | datetime(3)   | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
+-------------+---------------+------+-----+---------+-------+

and the problem is fixed!
Thank you, @CBroe!
